# javascript - document.form.textbox.style....can't seem to find this?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help point me in the right direction - I have the following in a function:

document.form1.textbox1.style.display = 'none';

which works fine.

But I'm trying to find a list of all the possible 'elements'(?) that could come after style, e.g. '.display=', '.length=' etc, but I don't know the proper name/terms so the searches i'm doing are not returning what I want.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

leddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html). Convert hyphenated-names to camelCase (e.g. backgroundColor not background-color).

Also see the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/css.html#CSS-extended-h2).

That said, in most cases it is usually better to modify the `element.className` (and have a pre–written, external style sheet) instead of modifying the `element.style.*`

Comment: thanks David, I'm looking at CSS and stylesheets at the moment, but it's hard to find some things when you don't know their names.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [this](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_style.asp)?

It also shows browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Style basically maps onto the CSS.  As such, display is a CSS property - this is what your setting.

Take a look at CSS and you should understand what you can and cannot set.

Hope this helps!

Ben

Comment: thanks for the reply Ben, I'm looking into CSS and stylesheets at the mo :)